# Python - Weighted Average from a single list

Tags: python, numpy

I have a single list as this:

```
prices = [10, 10, 10, 40, 40, 50]
```

and I would like to calculate the weighted average from this list, so the weight of the number 10 would be 3, weight of 40 would be 2 and weight of 50 would be 1. How do I do this without having 2 separated lists?

Comment: What did you try? You neeed some form of lookup for your weights, either a list of the same lenght or a dictionary seem prudent.

Comment: dont call variable `list` you shadow the build in `list()`

Comment: Is it a coincidence in your example that the weights correspond to the count of unique elements? If this is a pattern in your data, you don't need a separate list for the weights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You neeed some form of lookup for your weights, either a list of the same lenght or a dictionary seem prudent.

Compute it using a dictionary of weights:

```
l = [10, 10, 10, 40, 40, 50]
w = {10:3,40:2,50:1}

avg_w = sum(i*w[i] for i in l)/len(l)
print(avg_w)
```

or use a weight list:

```
w2= [3,3,3,2,2,1]
avg_w = sum(v*w2[i] for i,v in enumerate(l))/len(l)
print(avg_w)
```

Output:

```
50
```